# Laravel Route Parameters Not Trimmed (it normally works when whitespace is added)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('posts/{encoded_id}/{slug}', 'PostController@show')
```

... and it works fine:

```
http://example.test/posts/1Dl89aRjpk/this-is-some-title
```

But the "problem" is that it will also work when I add a **white space** **at the end of route parameter** `{encoded_id}`:

```
http://example.test/posts/1Dl89aRjpk /this-is-some-title

// or

http://example.test/posts/1Dl89aRjpk%20 /this-is-some-title

// or

http://example.test/posts/1Dl89aRjpk%20%20 /this-is-some-title
```

With whitespace added at the end - this will work normally and there is **no** 404:

```
Post::where('encoded_id', $encoded_id)->firstOrFail();
```

... but **why?** **And how can I make it to fail (to give 404)?**

Maybe because of the type of field in the DB (`CHAR`)?

```
$table->char('encoded_id', 10)
```

If that's why - is there any way to **configure MySQL in** `databases.php` so that it will prevent this?

Or maybe it has something to do with `.htaccess` (I'm using XAMPP / Windows)?

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

**EDIT:**

I'm asking why this is happening and how can I prevent it, not how to trim route parameter. For example, add white space at the end of the `question id` on stackoverflow url and you will get 404:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068436 /laravel-route-parameters-not-trimmed-it-normally-works-when-whitespace-is-added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to expected SQL behaviour. In your controller you receive the full `$encoded_id` with spaces. All what Laravel does for you, is calling an SQL select query with `WHERE`. SQL ignores trailing spaces in `WHERE` comparison.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933250/sql-server-where-condition-does-not-consider-white-spaces).

If you want a 404, replace spaces in the ID to some dummy character:

```
$encoded_id = str_replace(' ', '#', $encoded_id);
```

Do this only if it is guaranteed that the ID doesn't contain spaces or hash marks otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Building on balping's answer.  Some other solutions would be:

Replace all trailing spaces with #

```
preg_replace("/\s+$/", "#", $encoded_id);
```

Use trim in combination with str_pad and strlen.  This will trim the whitespaces from the front and back but pad the string with #'s so it's still the original length.

```
str_pad(trim($encoded_id), strlen($encoded_id), '#');
```